# SVG polygons not rendering when cloned from outside an SVG tag

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

I'm cloning an SVG hexagon 6 times with the method below, and everything works fine when I'm cloning a `<polygon>` element that's initially inside an `<svg>` tag:

```js
// Get SVG Container and prototype hexagon
const svgBox = document.querySelector("#workSVG");
const hexProto = document.querySelector(".workHex");
let hexClone, yPos;

// Clone 6 hexagons, and add to SVG container
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    hexClone = hexProto.cloneNode(true);
    yPos = (i + 1) * 50;
    hexClone.style.transform = "translateY(" + yPos + "px)";
    svgBox.appendChild(hexClone);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="workSVG" width="30" height="430">
  <!-- Cloned elements below -->
  <g class="workHex" style="">
    <polygon class="outie" points="0,15 7.5,2 22.5,2 30,15 22.5,28 7.5,28" ></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

However, if I clone the `<polygon>` element when it's initially NOT inside an `<svg>` tag, then they don't render:

```js
// Get SVG Container and prototype hexagon
const svgBox = document.querySelector("#workSVG");
const hexProto = document.querySelector(".workHex");
let hexClone, yPos;

// Clone 6 hexagons, and add to SVG container
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    hexClone = hexProto.cloneNode(true);
    yPos = (i + 1) * 50;
    hexClone.style.transform = "translateY(" + yPos + "px)";
    svgBox.appendChild(hexClone);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="workSVG" width="30" height="430">
  <!-- Cloned elements below -->
</svg>

<g class="workHex" style="">
  <polygon class="outie" points="0,15 7.5,2 22.5,2 30,15 22.5,28 7.5,28" ></polygon>
</g>
```

Why aren't they rendering in the second instance? I'm inspecting the DOM, and they do get added to the `<svg>`, exactly in the same manner as in the first method, except they won't render. Does the `<svg>` element not recognize these children when they get initialized outside an SVG tag?

[image]

Comment: Because they aren't SVG elements in that case, they are HTML elements that happen to have the same names as SVG elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is there a way to tell the `<svg>` tag to re-read them, or trigger some sort of parsing mechanism so it'll recognize them?

Comment: Why not just make them a child of an <svg> element in the first place.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, there are a few ways to deal with this. I could also add `display: none` to the prototype after I'm done cloning it so it won't show. I guess my question was more about the technical explanation behind the behavior, which you answered with your first comment.

Comment: Why not using [<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) elements instead.?

Comment: @enxaneta That's another good suggestion I hadn't thought of!